# Amending last git commit message creates diverged feature branch version?

Tags: git, version-control

I have a feature branch and want to alter previous commit message. There I perform a command:

```
git commit --amend
```

It works as expected when the commit is not pushed yet and so a new commit is created and replaced with the previous one (locally). However, if the commit is pushed to remote branch then a diverged branch version is created and therefore I see 1 pull and 1 push. Therefore I need to make commit merge which actually merges altered commit into feature branch by creating completely new commit. However, I don't need this redundant commit.

I know we should never alter commits in public branches, however it's my personal feature branch which I use for pushing and sometimes working from home, therefore I need to push. So the question is, is it expected behaviour or I'm missing something and that's why I'm asked to perform merge commit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you understand the rationale behind git's behavior in the scenario you described. If you're the only one committing to this branch, then working around the merge could be accomplished by using the `-f` flag when pushing the branch to the remote repo like so:

```
git push -f origin master
```